# R match date in one table if between two date columns in second table over category

Tags: r

Using base R only, I'm trying to iterate and test if table1$"DATE" is >= table2$"START" & <= table2$"STOP" where table1$"EVENT" == table2$"EVENT". I initially thought to get unique categories from table1$"EVENT" and then subset via looping then outer-joining to table2 and after that using for-loop to iterate each table1 row against table2 rows to return the value but for loops are slow and my real data set has over 3 million rows and is grows daily. In Python I'd probably try something with pd.intervalrange or some similar approach.

This is the table of events I want to return a value to based on if DATE is between table2's START and STOP columns where EVENT matches in both table1 and table2.

table1

[image: enter code here]

table2 (lookup table)

[image]

desired outcome

[image]

Comment: Please add data using `dput`, we cannot use screenshots to test any possible solution. [Read here on how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: i think u are looking for a non-equi join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R, wouldn't give you the most efficient approach especially on large data but here is one attempt

```
df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date, '%m/%d/%Y')
df2$Start <- as.Date(df2$Start, '%m/%d/%Y')
df2$Stop <- as.Date(df2$Stop, '%m/%d/%Y')

df1$result <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), function(x) {
   inds <- df2$Event == df1$Event[x] & 
           df1$Date[x] >= df2$Start & df1$Date[x] <= df2$Stop
   if (any(inds)) df2$Return[which.max(inds)]  else NA
})

df1
#  Event       Date result
#1     A 2000-01-01   <NA>
#2     A 2019-02-15    abc
#3     B 2000-01-01   <NA>
#4     B 2019-02-15    bar
#5     B 2019-12-12   <NA>
#6     C 2017-07-07   <NA>
```

**data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(Event = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B','C'), Date = c('1/1/2000', 
                  '2/15/2019', '1/1/2000', '2/15/2019', '12/12/2019','7/7/2017'),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(Event = c('A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A'), 
       Start = c('1/1/2019','2/1/2019', '1/1/2019','2/1/2019', '3/1/2019'), 
       Stop = c('1/31/2019','2/28/2019', '1/31/2019', '2/28/2019', '3/30/2019'), 
       Return = c('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'abc', 'xyz'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: @ Ronak Shah, Wow, that works perfectly. Thank you so much!